# Fitting newer metal exterior door to older (50's) door frame

Tags: doors, exterior, frame

The new door fits in the frame but #1 is very tight side to side and figure if I could shave 1/8" off the latch side it would be enough to open and close properly and #2 the metal door is thicker by about 1/4" than the old hollow core door and if I could shave 1/4" off the stop part of the frame it would fit fine and be able to have some weather stripping. I'm just not sure how to make these adjustments (cuts) and still have it look decent.  I do not want to replace or remove the frame itself since this one has the inset for the exterior storm door and being an older (50's) home don't want to disturb anything possibly hazardous. Looking for suggestions. I have circular saws and a router but corners would be an issue.

Comment: @Alaskaman poor reading on my part. Deleted the answer.

Comment: Can't you trim some off of the rough opening? I assume this is a pre-hung door and so you are installing the door with the jamb, right? Is the rough opening  brick or stone which you cannot trim? If you install a metal door which is tight to a metal jamb, I think you will regret it.

Comment: No, this not a pre-hung door (it is just a metal door) and the wood frame or jamb was built into this house in the 1950's. As previously stated, I don't want to remove or replace the original frame (or door jamb) and disturb any possibly hazardous material. If this was a wood door I would just trim the door but there isn't enough wood on the sides of this metal door to trim.